# Refused to execute JSX Babel?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I start to learn React and I try to run this page but I caught this error :
Refused to execute script from 'https://unpkg.com/browse/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Can anyone helps me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> React work </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/browse/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id='react-root'></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
    class Bonjour extends React.Component
    {
        render()
        {
            return (
                <h1> Hello from React </h1>
            )
        }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
    <Bonjour/>,
    document.getElementById('react-root')
    )

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your link is wrong. The /browse is:

https://unpkg.com/browse/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js

This is a *webpage*, not a `.js` file. Click the "View Raw" button to get to the plain JS:

https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js

Use that instead, and you get:

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id='react-root'></div>
<script type="text/babel">
    class Bonjour extends React.Component
    {
        render()
        {
            return (
                <h1> Hello from React </h1>
            )
        }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
    <Bonjour/>,
    document.getElementById('react-root')
    )
</script>
```

But, a suggestion - only use Babel Standalone for debugging, if possible. For real apps, once they're ready for public consumption, better to transpile the JSX on your own, then serve *that* to clients. (Babel Standalone makes *clients* transpile the code themselves, which requires quite a lot of overhead)

Comment: Thanks a lot. So how can I transpile the JSX on my own? Do you have any link for me please?

Comment: [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) is a good starting point, though you could also tie all the packages together manually if you wanted