# React not loading on html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to add react to a html page without node.

```js
function Hello(){
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

main.js is the javascript.
Can you help me out with this?
Thanks

Comment: Works for me... (but [don't use Babel Standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65228599) except for toy snippets you're demonstrating for others, and [use `createRoot`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71698061) in React 18)

Comment: Does this help? Maybe the issue is you're not enumerating your presets. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230101/single-react-component-rendering-with-babel-standalone-with-only-index-html-and

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: @Macilquham No, I don't see any errors in the real version, not stacksnippets

Comment: If I run your code locally I get a cors error in chrome, if I deploy it to my local iis instance it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I don't know why this happens but this only happens when the react code is in another file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="ot"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
    var t = 0;
function App(){
  function enter(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    t++
   document.getElementById('ot').innerHTML = `You Clicked The Button ${t} times`
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={enter}>Click me</button>
    </div>
    )
}

const root = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root)
</script>
</html>
```

So that works because for some reason react doesn't work for me in a different file, I have to use inline js. Thank you all for trying to help, and I hope I can help other poeple with this same problem. By the way, there were no errors in the console

Answer (score 1):

Use `ReactDOM.createRoot(rootNode).render(<App />);`

Reference- https://17.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-reference.html#createroot

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put the scripts inside the `<body>` it might work as the elements have to be loaded to be found by the selectors.

For example:

```html
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <!-- Scripts Here -->
</body>
```

In my browser (**Firefox**) it works!

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you see any error in the developer console?

Comment: In my browser this works perfectly locally and I don't get any CORS errors! I don't  see the problem in the code. It may be an internal react or babel error.